# Dropdown filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of data which I need to bind it to dropdown list in angularjs.

```
$scope.offerFilter = [  {title :'Matching Ticket' , Status : '1'},
     {title :'Non-matched Ticket',Status : '2'},
     {title :'Rejected Ticket',Status :  '3'},
     {title: 'Not Sale', Status: '0'}]
```

I have binded the title to my dropdown list. When I select the option from dropdown list my page not getting filtered. I don't know where I am going wrong.

**My View**:

```
<select ng-model="SelectedStatus" ng-options="type.Status as type.title for type in offerFilter" style="float:right;width:40%;font-family:'Segoe UI';font-size:12px;">
                    <option value="">All {{type.title}}</option>
                </select>
<md-list-item dir-paginate="ticket in ticketInventoryList.data.hits.hits | itemsPerPage:10 | filter : SelectedStatus">
            <div style="width:15%">
                <img alt="{{ ticket._source.SeriesName }}" ng-src="{{ ticket._source.ImagePath }}" class="md-avatar" style="width:90%" />

            </div>
     </md-list-item>
```

**My controller:**

I have declared the `ng-model` variabe as `$scope.SelectedStatus='';`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using many directives that are not commonly used. Probably you wrote them or they are from some library. It's hard for people to help you, if they don't understand your code. So create a working example like a plunker or js fiddle showing your problem, so people can help you easily

Comment: I have provided all the information here itself and I explained my issue also.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will be work for you

```
<select ng-model="SelectedStatus" ng-change="changeValue(SelectedStatus)" ng-options="type.Status as type.title for type in offerFilter" style="float:right;width:40%;font-family:'Segoe UI';font-size:12px;">
                    <option value="">All {{type.title}}</option>
                </select>
```

Please this all code in controller

```
$scope.isShow=false;
$scope.changeValue=function(selectedValue){
    if(condtion you want){
    $scope.isShow=false;
    $timeout(function(){
            $scope.isShow=true;
    },500);
    }
}

<md-list-item dir-paginate="ticket in ticketInventoryList.data.hits.hits | itemsPerPage:10 | filter : SelectedStatus" data-ng-if="isShow">
            <div style="width:15%">
                <img alt="{{ ticket._source.SeriesName }}" ng-src="{{ ticket._source.ImagePath }}" class="md-avatar" style="width:90%" />

            </div>
     </md-list-item>
```

Your change to refresh directive when select value is changed.

Comment: It just showing the list of data after clicking the dropdown option. My issue is my view page not getting filtered based on the dropdown selection

Comment: dir-paginate="ticket in filtered = (mapList | filterMaps : ticketInventoryList.data.hits.hits : SelectedStatus) | itemsPerPage: 10 ". Use this place of your dir-paginate

Comment: I have used in the way you suggested but still its not working. `<md-list-item dir-paginate="ticket in filtered = (mapList | filterMaps : ticketInventoryList.data.hits.hits : SelectedStatus)  | itemsPerPage:10 " data-ng-if="isShow">
            <div style="width:15%">
                <img alt="{{ ticket._source.SeriesName }}" ng-src="{{ ticket._source.ImagePath }}" class="md-avatar" style="width:90%" />

            </div>`

Comment: have you try with this? dir-paginate="ticket in filtered = (mapList | filterMaps : ticketInventoryList.data.hits.hits | SelectedStatus) | itemsPerPage:10 "